# check std::cin variable type

Tags: c++, std, cin

i am learning about functions and function arguments. i am attempting to right a function called `int repeat(int rep){...}` below is the code for the function `int repeat()`.

```
int repeat(int rep){
    std::cout << "Do you wish to factorial another number? Y or N: " <<
        std::endl;
    char c1;
    restart:
    std::cin >> c1; /* pretend user input is "7". the below if statement should execute the `throw`            statement. However it does not evaluate the if statement as true. and passes over it.*/
    try{
        if (std::cin.fail()){
            throw std::runtime_error(" Must enter y for yes or n for no.");
        }
        if (c1 == 'y' || c1 == 'Y'){
            return rep = 1;
        }
        else{
            //system("pause");
            return rep = 0;
        }
    }
    catch (std::runtime_error err2){
        std::cout << err2.what() << std::endl;
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore();
        goto restart;
    }
}
```

the issue in my code appears with the first if statement: 
`if (std::cin.fail()){   throw std::runtime_error(" Must enter y for yes or n for no.");
}`

i am attempting to use `std::cin.fail()` to test rather the input that is stored in the variable `char c1` is in fact a char type. Example: if the user inputs a number into `c1` then the if statement should execute the `throw` statement. however it does not happen. Can anyone assist in making the if statement execute correctly if a user inputs a non char type into the `std::cin >> c1`?

Note: i have used this method in a different part of the program to test if an input into`std::cin` is of type int and the if statement works as intended.

Comment: Do not use exceptions for flow control. Also, `7` is a perfectly valid character.

Comment: And do not use `goto`.

Comment: @Ed Heal: the book i am using strongly warns against using the `goto`. however i am still a baby when it comes to programming and have only learned so much. what would be a better "best practice" to control the loop/flow control?

Comment: @T.C. what are some of the issue i should be concerned with using exceptions for flow control ?

Comment: @user3089453 - 1. Why not have a real name than userX? 2. Exceptions are exceptions - this is not one. 3. Re-read the chapter on loops, while-for